Why (and when) can we "instantiate" a random variable in conditional distribution
Suppose $g(X,Y)$ and $Y$ are jointly continuous. Is it true that $g(X,y)$ and $Y$ are also jointly continuous with $f_{g(X,Y) | Y} (x,y) = f_{g(X,y) | Y} (x,y)$? Or assuming that $g(X,y)$ and $Y$ are also jointly continuous, does it imply that $f_{g(X,Y) | Y} (x,y) = f_{g(X,y) | Y} (x,y)$?

The expression $f_{g(X,y) | Y} (x,y)$ is difficult to understand. The density function is a global, non-pointwise concept.

@Speltzu This means the conditional density of the random variable $g(X,y)$ for a fixed $y$ and $Y$, at $g(X,y) = x$ and $Y=y$.

The problem is what version of $f_{g(X,y)|Y}$ we take. $f_{g(X,y)|Y}$ is not a function, it is a class of functions that differ from each other in a set of null measure.

@Speltzu, this is not a problem as far as I know, because we can identify a.e equal functions, and they serve the same purpose as density. If one such function is a density then all funtions that differ by only a null set should be density. You can understand the equality in the question as a.e quality if you wish.

$g(X,y_0)$ is a random variable, for each $y$ we obtain another: $"g(X,y_0)|Y=y"$, which we assume would have a density function $f_{g(X,y_0)|Y}(y)$. But the function $F(y)="g(X,y_0)|Y=y"$, which associates to each $y$ the random variable $"g(X,y_0)|Y=y"$, is defined a.e., so its value at $y_0$ could be anything.
